# Python: Transform a STL-Mesh with a transformation matrix

Tags: python

I want to change the position and rotation of the Object inside my STL file permanantly, bygiving an Transformation matrix and a vector. Do you know how i could realize something like this:

```
newMesh = Mesh * transfromationMatrix - Vector
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it with: numpy-stl
Its a nice library for python. It has a function called transform(), which uses a 4x4 homogeneours Transformationsmatrix as an input